# SVG Mask Using Stroke Property

Tags: html, css

I want to mask an image with an SVG path. However, I don't want the image to be masked within the body of the path. It should be masked in the stroke of the path itself.

So if I had a square masking an image, the image would show up on the edges of the square instead of inside the square. For purposes of animating this mask later on, I want the thickness of the path to be defined using a stroke. The idea is that I can mask an image in the edges of a square and then use stroke-dasharray to animate the mask. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Did you tried it ? Where it didn't work. It should work : https://jsfiddle.net/78f303eL/

Answer (score -2):

Why bother using SVG?

You can achieve the same thing with two `div` elements.

```css
#image {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: url('https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/enhanced/webdr03/2013/9/13/11/enhanced-buzz-13525-1379086895-24.jpg') center/cover;
}

#mask {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="image">
  <div id="mask">
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ztf1cv08/1/

**Or do you need the middle to "transparent" so that you can actually see the background??**